# Order QuerySet depends of ordering Many to Many Field

Tags: python, django, orm, sql-order-by

I have two models, one of them contain many to many field. I want to order all values in many to many field in ascending order.

[My data and expected result - IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELxSY.png)

In first column are all my data. Second column show result after using ordering by many to many field - it's dublicate the data. The third column is expected result - for getting correct result I transform my queryset to pandas dataframe and make all ordering to get correct result. But such method is very slowly.

Is there another way to order data as I need.

**models.py**

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, related_name = 'publications')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

**views.py** - first two function I used to get correct result.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article, Publication
import pandas as pd

def get_value_from_list(value, iter=0, sort_direct=True):
    try:
        value = value[iter]
    except IndexError:
        # value =  999999 if sort_direct == True else 0
        value = 0 
    return value

def get_unique_val(qs, sort_direct):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'headline', 'name', 'count'])

    for numb, item in enumerate(qs):
        df.loc[numb, 'id'] = item.id
        df.loc[numb, 'headline'] = item
        df.loc[numb, 'name'] = item.publications.values_list('title', flat=True)
        df.loc[numb, 'count'] = item.publications.count()

    max_val = df['count'].values.max()
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep="last")
    for i in range(0, max_val):
        df[f'col_{i}'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: get_value_from_list(x, i, sort_direct))

    sort_by_col = [ f'col_{i}' for i in range(max_val) ]
    df2 = df.sort_values(sort_by_col, ascending=sort_direct)
    ids = df2['headline'].tolist()
    return ids

def index(request):
    df = Article.objects.all()
    ids_asc = get_unique_val(df, True)
    context = { 
        'asc': Article.objects.order_by('publications__title'),
        'desc': ids_asc,
        'full': Article.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context = context)
```

From **https://github.com/amyard/test_many** you can clone repo with this two models and views, and sqlite database with data from picture.